# WP7 Textbox with title inside of textbox

Tags: windows-phone-7

I would like to have a textbox that lets a user enter some text (obviously). Let's say it's 'Title'. Is there a pre-built control that shows the name of the field (Title in this case) inside of the text box and then have it clear out when the user enter the field. Example: The search box at the top of this page has 'Search' but when you enter the box it goes away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Watermarked TextBox](http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/articles/WP7-WatermarkedTextBox-custom-control)

I think I remember it also being in the Mango Silverlight Toolkit too, correct me if I'm wrong:
    [Mango Silverlight Toolkit](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/releases/view/71550)

Comment: Thanks but I was hoping to avoid building it myself. I'll update my emulator to mango and try the PhoneTextBox. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is an example. Put the GotFocus and LostFocus event in your textbox(in .xaml page).

```
<TextBox x:Name="UrlTextBox" Text="Search" Margin="0,0,98,0" GotFocus="UrlTextBox_GotFocus" LostFocus="UrlTextBox_LostFocus"/>
```

In xaml.cs page, add the following codes-

```
    private void UrlTextBox_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (UrlTextBox.Text == "Search")
        {
            UrlTextBox.Text = "";
            SolidColorBrush Brush1 = new SolidColorBrush();
            Brush1.Color = Colors.Gray;
            UrlTextBox.Foreground = Brush1;
        }

        else
        {
            char[] strDataAsChars = UrlTextBox.Text.ToCharArray();
            int i = 0;
            for (i = UrlTextBox.SelectionStart - 1; ((i >= 0) &&
                               (strDataAsChars[i] != ' ')); --i) ;
            int selBegin = i + 1;
            for (i = UrlTextBox.SelectionStart; ((i < strDataAsChars.Length) &&
                                              (strDataAsChars[i] != ' ')); ++i) ;
            int selEnd = i;
            UrlTextBox.Select(selBegin, selEnd - selBegin);
        }
    }

    private void UrlTextBox_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (UrlTextBox.Text == String.Empty)
        {
            UrlTextBox.Text = "Search";
            SolidColorBrush Brush2 = new SolidColorBrush();
            Brush2.Color = Colors.Gray;
            UrlTextBox.Foreground = Brush2;
        }
    }
```